# Как слить две строки, вставив символы одной строки между символами другой строки

Tags: java, строки

К примеру есть строки:

```
String str1 = "13579", str2 = "2468";
```

Как получить `"123456789"` ?

Comment: у вас могут быть только цифры или и буквы тоже? ваши попытки можете показать?

Comment: @Andrew, я так понимаю не важно, доже если и буквы, будет тоже самое. А если  вставлять слова между слов, то их надо будет сплит. Мои попытки закончились после написания этих строк))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str1 = "13579"; 
        String str2 = "2468"; 
         
        String res = "";
        for(int i = 0; i< str1.length(); i++)  
        {
           
            char a1 = str1.charAt(i);
            
             if (i<str2.length()) {
                 char a2 = str2.charAt(i);
                 res = res + a1 + a2;
                 
             }
            else res = res + a1;
        } 
        
        System.out.println(res);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.stream((str1 + str2).split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining())
```